# WP8 LongListMultiSelector - not binding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, toolkit, longlistselector

I have LongListMultiSelector in my project, which is binding with ListProductInRecipe2P. When I load page with LongListMultiSelector, list is loading but when I want delete Items LongListMultiSelector not is update.

---

This is my code:
XAML:

```XAML
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="ListProductsSelectedItems" ItemsSource="{Binding ListProductInRecipe2P}">
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

---

C# (behind code):

```C#
private void DelProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = ListProductsSelectedItems.SelectedItems;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var temp = list[i] as Fridge;
        App.ViewModel.ListProductInRecipe2P.Remove(temp);
    }
}
```

and C# (viewModel):

```C#
private List<Fridge> ListProductInRecipe2;
public List<Fridge> ListProductInRecipe2P 
{
    get { return ListProductInRecipe2;}
    set
    {
        ListProductInRecipe2 = value;
        changeValue("ListProductInRecipe2P");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ObservableCollection instead.  It will raise the INotifyProperty event for you.

Learn more @ [MSDN ObservableCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.95).aspx)

---

```C#
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

private ObservableCollection<Fridge> ListProductInRecipe2;
public ObservableCollection<Fridge> ListProductInRecipe2P 
{
    get { return ListProductInRecipe2;}
    set
    {
        ListProductInRecipe2 = value;
        // changeValue("ListProductInRecipe2P");
    }
}
```